# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended with psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, psycopg2

So I've been trying to get this query to run from python with psycopg2 but it gives me the error
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
While if I try to run the query in the oracle DB it goes through without a problem.

All it does is get the count from one table and compare it with the count of another and returns PASS or FAIL.

If anyone could help identify what could be the cause I would be very grateful.

Here's the query:

```
'WITH QA AS ( SELECT COUNT(*) C FROM QAAUTO.FactInternetSales) 
,DEV AS (SELECT COUNT (*) C FROM qaauto.LoyaltyProgramA) 
SELECT "Records count" AS TEST_NAME 
   ,QA.C AS QA_RECORDS 
   ,DEV.C AS DEV_RECORDS 
   ,CASE WHEN DEV.C > 0 AND DEV.C = QA.C THEN "PASS" ELSE "FAIL" END AS RESULT
FROM QA,DEV ; '
```

python code that runs it:

```
def generate_results(self, driver):
    for tce in self.testCaseExecutors:
        testExecutorId = tce["testcaseexecutorid"]
        script = tce["script"]
        failOutputScript = tce["failoutputscript"]

        result = run_Script(driver, script)
        output = None

        if result == 'PASS':
            stateid = 'PASS'
        elif result == 'FAIL':
            stateid = 'FAIL'
            

        tcResult = (testExecutorId, stateid, output)
        self.testCaseResults.append(tcResult)

 def run_Script(driver, script):
    result = driver.fetchall(script, {})
    return result[0]
```

in my case *script* contains the query posted above

Comment: You haven't shown the code to actually execute the query. There's not much anyone can help with if you give the working query outside of the context of psycopg2

Comment: Would removing semi-colon, here: `FROM QA,DEV ; '` do any good?

Comment: @Littlefoot facepalm, you're correct. For whatever reason it was the cause of the issue. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the semi-colon at the end of the query was causing the error.